# Pymatbridge win32 error (trying to install matlab_kernel in Python)

Tags: python, matlab

My goal is to install matlab_kernel on my anaconda so that I can run Jupyter with matlab kernel on my smaller laptop. However, there is a problem, when I run pip install matlab_kernel I get an error when the terminal is trying to install the pymatbridge. It says: ValueError: pymatbridge does not work on win32. I have found the github page for pymatbridge and there was a ticket for this issue I believe: https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/issues/122

I think I am probably misinterpreting what is said there in the very bottom. I am interpreting installing from source as saying pip install pymatbrudge in the terminal, but that does not work. Therefore I must be misinterpreting. What does installing from source mean, and how do I do it?

EDIT: Alright I have downloaded the master branch zip file and ran the setup.py from the source directory, I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

The Python-Matlab bridge doesn't work on 32 bit Windows machines out of the box.

To make this work for you, you might need to also compile the messenger mex file, which is in this folder: https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/tree/master/pymatbridge/messenger

This is done by running: `python make.py` in that directory. After compilation of the messenger succeeds, you can run the setup.py file to install everything. I hope that works -- I don't have access to a Windows machine to help debug these issues.

You might also want to take a look at some of the comments on this previous SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716426/installing-pymatbridge-on-windows